# Auto replace ID with name (excel/google docs)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for some way how to do this. So let's say that I have a table where I have IDs and items, next to each other. And next to this table I have another, where I'll put these data again, but in different order.

So let me show you an example:

```
01  bacon

02  tomato

03  capsicum

04  ham

05  cheese
```

And there is mine question: I want to write only 'bacon' and Excel will automatically replace it with the ID '01'. Or if I write ham, excel will replace it with '04'.  Is there any way how to make this possible?

Comment: if you mean "replace" literally then you can achieve it only with a macro, there are plenty of support materials on the internet on writing macros. If you just mean enter in a new cell, then `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions will help you.

Comment: It's very easy. Maybe? You'll have to change your question because you stated, "I want to write only 'bacon'". Excel isn't used to write or type things. Excel is a database and uses Cells as references. Mate Juhasz has a good idea and it makes perfect sense, but when I read your question it looks like you aren't sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that:

1. your translate table is in columns **A** & **B**
2. your data entry column is column **C**
3. the data entry column as been formatted as *"00"* (*to allow leading zeros to be entered*)

Place the following Event Macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim C As Range, A As Range, B As Range
    Dim t As String

    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set B = Range("B:B")
    Set C = Range("C:C")

    If Intersect(C, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        t = Target.Text
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            Target.Value = B(.Match(t, A, 0))
        End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

***NOTE:***

You should also include error-handlers to cover operator errors!